# SQLAlchemy: how to recreate the table

Tags: sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy, how to recreate the table. 
 first, I create a table ToDoTask, with 4 columns: content, id, priority and status by the following code:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class ToDoTask(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'todotask'
     content = Column(String(250), nullable = False)
     id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
     priority = Column(Integer)
     status = Column(String(8))

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///todotask.db')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

then if I found I need to redesign the table by add a new column,for example `Time`. I add the column into the Class, and rerun, but checked with `inspect` function and found the `Time` column is not added.

so how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it right, I think you should use a migration tool like [Alembic](https://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)